# How can I dull the reflection effect of an environment map (ie. make it blurred / matte)?

Tags: three.js

I'm currently rendering a skybox to a `THREE.CubeCamera` target and am then using that target as the environment map on a material. The idea being that I want to have the colour of a cube affected by the colour of the sky around it, though not fully reflecting it (like how a white matte cube would look in the real world).

For example, here is what I have so far applying the environment map to a `THREE.LambertMaterial` or `THREE.PhongMaterial` with `reflectivity` set to `0.7` (same results):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice in the first image that the horizon line is clearly visible (this is at sunset when it's most obvious) and that the material is very reflective. The second image shows the same visible horizon line, which moves with the camera as you orbit. The third image shows the box at midday with blue sky above it (notice how the blue is reflected very strongly).

The effect I'm trying to aim for is a duller, perhaps blurred representation of what we can already see working here. I want the sky to affect the cube but I don't want to fully reflect it, instead I want each side of the cube to have a much more subtle effect without a visible horizon line.

I've experimented with the `reflection` property of the materials without much luck. Yes, it reduces the reflection effect but it also removes most of the colouring taken from the skybox. I've also tried the `shininess` property of `THREE.PhongMaterial` but that didn't seem to do much, if anything.

I understand that environment maps are meant to be reflections, however my hope is that there is a way to achieve what I'm after. I want a reflection of the sky, I just need it to be much less precise and instead more blurred / matte.

What could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this writing my own custom shader based on physically based rendering shading model.

I use *cook-torrance* model that consider roughness of the material for specular contribution. It's not an easy argument that I can talk in this answer, you can find great references here http://graphicrants.blogspot.it/ at the *specular BRDF* article.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218267/manual-selection-lod-of-mipmaps-in-a-fragment-shader-using-three-js) you can find how I achieve the blurry reflection depending on material roughness.

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing a different set of textures that were blurred to be the cubemap for the object.